# What happens to Blue Origin's New Shepard capsule if their one engine fails?

Tags: rockets, commercial, blue-origin, new-shepard

What are the plans for the New Shepard capsule if the engine fails near the start of its flight? Are there plans for any sort of ballistic escape like the SpaceX capsule?

Comment: It's not in Blue Origin MO to publish upcoming dates. So their "abort at Max-Q (Maximum velocity)" test will be announced only 1 day prior. I recon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The capsule is equipped with a Launch Escape System capable of aborting from pad or in-flight.

The pad abort was already tested in 2012:

http://www.nasa.gov/exploration/commercial/crew/blue-origin-padescapetest.html

And the in flight escape was tested in October 2016:

Comment: And used for real in September '22.